# online game best-practice

Tags: django, web-applications, client-server

I'm developing a django-based MMO, and I'm wondering what would be the best way for server-client communication. The solutions I found are:

- periodical AJAX calls
- keeping a connection alive and sending data through it

**Later edit:**

This would consist in "you have a message", "user x attacked you", "your transport to x has arrived" and stuff like this. They could grow in number (something like 1/second), but for a typical user they shouldn't reach 1/minute

Comment: There is no way we can help you say what will be the best practice without knowing the demands of your MMO game. What is the required time an event may take before being displayed at client, how many events/time do you have, ... ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There's also a third technique involving "hanging" queries:

- Client requests an updated page (or whatever)
- Server doesn't answer right away
- Sometime before the request times out, there's a state update in the server, and the server finally answers the client, which can then update.
- If there really is nothing new to tell the client within the update period, then the server responds before the timeout with a "no news" message, and the client starts up another "hanging" request.

Advantages:

- Client doesn't have to do Ajax. You could even make regular HTML pages "interactive" like this.
- Probably not quite as much senseless polling traffic.

Disadvantages:

- Server needs to keep more active connections open, and service them at least once per timeout period. Also,
- depending on how well the server code supports multi-threading (does PHP provide any help there?), it may be more difficult to code than AJAX response handling.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's applicable to what you're looking for, but there's a pretty good live example of lightweight server-client communication using node.js for a simple chat service:

http://chat.nodejs.org/

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at [crossbar](https://github.com/crossbario/crossbar)

> Crossbar.io is an open-source server software that allows developers
>   to create distributed systems, composed of application components
>   which are loosely coupled, communicate in (soft) real-time and can be
>   implemented in different languages